# Editing polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, polygon-creation

I have a shapefile of polygons. What I want to do is take some areas and discard others. For example, I have a map of USA (shapefile). I want to take California only and make another shapefile.

How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? See "Editing": https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html

Comment: This is a very basic question. Have you consulted the QGis documentation or read any other tutorial?

Answer (score 5):

Select the California polygon using the select features tool. It will turn yellow.

Right click on the layer in the layers panel usually on the left hand side.

Choose Save As.

Make sure "Save only selected features" is ticked.